# Expect error to be thrown out of next handler of observable, testing Angular with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine, observable

In Angular application have a controller with following method

```
onClick(): void {
    this.http
        .get('some/endpoint')
        .subscribe(
            (response) => {
                const editUrl = this.service.composeUrl(response);

                if (!editUrl) {
                    // want to test this error is thrown, when editUrl is null
                    throw Error('Cannot construct valid URL');
                }

                // do something else
            },
            () => {
                // request clean up
            }
        );
}
```

I would like to write Jasmine test to verify, that if the `editUrl` cannot be composed out of response an error will be thrown.

```
it('when call is successful but editUrl cannot be constructed, then error is thrown', () => {
    mockHttp.get = jasmine
            .createSpy()
            .and.returnValue(of({}));


    mockService.composeUrl= jasmine
            .createSpy()
            .and.returnValue(null);

    expect(() => { component.onClick() }).toThrowError();
});
```

My test fails with:

> Error: Expected function to throw an Error.

But I also see in the browser console, that the error was thrown `Uncaught Error: Cannot construct valid URL`

I think the problem is in that Error is thrown in the next handler of http observable, and that's somehow running out of jasmine context.

I could fix it by extracting anonymous next handler into named function and test directly that function, but I prefer having subscribe with anonymous arrow functions.

Comment: You can't test this because there's no point throwing an error from inside a subscribe. `onClick` is a void function anyway. You'd have to test that the `do something else` _doesn't_ happen.

Comment: I would like to elaborate a bit on throwing error from inside a subscribe. A part of our Angular application have to be in line with a backend configuration. And if the `editUrl` cannot be composed it actually indicates a configuration problem on the backend. So I want to throw error, which is handled by global error handler and displayed in user friendly way to admin.

Imho, it's a valid reason to throw an error form a subscribe handler.

Comment: Thanks though  for a suggestion to test that `do something else` was not executed, that's also a way to write that test. Ideally I would like to catch the error and check the message, but not sure if this is possible.

Comment: As you're seeing, that error doesn't bubble up to the caller (because it's happening in the callback you pass to `.subscribe`, not `onClick` itself). I'd guess it doesn't go to your global error handler either.

Comment: There is token `ErrorHandler` (https://angular.io/api/core/ErrorHandler), to which you can provide your own custom error handling code and it will catch even errors throw within `.subscribe`. It works, I've tested it. For the test I will go with your recommendation, though.