# How to test method throwing error inside the handler of observable?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a service class that communicates outside and

```
public login(token: string) {
  const _this = this;

  return this.httpClient
    .post('url', { idToken: token }, 'httpOptions')
    .pipe(
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        return this.handleCommError(error);
        //return of([new AuthenticateResponse(...)]);
      })
    )
    .subscribe((res: AuthenticateResponse) => {
       ... handle res
    });
}

handleCommError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
  console.log('trying to handle comm error');
  console.log(error);
  this.handleError(AuthService.CommunicationErrorCode, `Error trying to auth: ${error.error.detail}`);
  return throwError(`Could not Auth. Try again or contact support.`);
}
```

I've implemented tests that handle the successful response and would like to test the case when communication error happened.

Here is how my test looks:

```
let httpClientSpy: { post: jasmine.Spy };

describe('AuthState', () => {
  let authService: AuthService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
        httpClientSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('HttpClient', ['post']);
        authService = new AuthService(httpClientSpy as any);
  });

  fit('login should fail due to communication error', () => {
    const err = new HttpErrorResponse({ error: 'Some error' });
    httpClientSpy.post.and.returnValue(throwError(err));

    expect(authService).toBeTruthy();

    authService.loggedIn.subscribe((loggedIn) => {
      console.log(`loggedIn event: ${loggedIn}`);
      expect(loggedIn).toBeFalse();
    });

    expect(() => {
      authService.handleCommError(err);
    }).toThrowError();

    authService.login('3rdPartyToken');
});
```

Test execution gives this error:

```
 Error: Expected function to throw an Error.
    at <Jasmine>
    at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/auth/AuthState.spec.ts:84:8)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:364:1)
    at ProxyZoneSpec.push.QpwO.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:292:1)
```

Method 'handleCommError' is called as I see the 'trying to handle comm error' message in the console, but somehow jasmine does not see that my method throws an error.

I feel I'm missing something very basic, but what is that?

**What do I do wrong?**

**I've seen a similar question** ([Expect error to be thrown out of next handler of observable, testing Angular with Jasmine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68632482/expect-error-to-be-thrown-out-of-next-handler-of-observable-testing-angular-wit)) and people suggest that "you don't need to throw an error inside of subscribe" but in my case I do have to throw an error to avoid further execution of the subscribers in the pipe.

As an option, I could convert the error into a 'valid' message and handle it as part of '.subscribe' but this does not smell right to me.

Comment: Btw, why people recommend using 'pipe' and 'catchError' before 'subscribe'? I've copied the code from one of examples, but don't really understand the value of doing that? The same can be achieved with 'err' handled inside of 'subscribe'...?

Answer (score 1):

Khm, I guess I found the answer, at least one of the solid options.

I need to add error handled into the 'subscribe' portion:

```
  .subscribe(
    (res: AuthenticateResponse) => {
      ... handle res
    },
    (err: any) => {
      console.log(`handling error`);
      console.log(err);
      ... handle err
    }
  );
```

And handle the error gracefully. Or just rethrow it again in which case I'd still come back to the original question.

Reading the comments to the references article, I've noticed the suggestion to use https://angular.io/api/core/ErrorHandler ... and this might be the way to go... Still need to figure out how to use it.